# SSRS to send report only if there is data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am preparing a report that keeps track of unassigned new people under a manager. If there is a new person at the company not yet assigned to a manager, they will show up on this report that will hopefully be emailed out. I have the query for the report but my question falls under;

I have access to SSRS enterprise edition so I am able to do data driven subscriptions but how should I go about that? I'm unsure on what to query or my paths that I am able to write this query. I am a tad bit unfamiliar with data driven queries, I apologize.

One thing that I researched on is having the query set to if it returns no rows, the query will not send, but if it has any rows, it sends out to email groups.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can bind the email:To to the result of a SP. The trick is how to determine if the report will have no data. You may need to run the SP that produces the report results within the SP that drives the list of emails.

Comment: Would it be possible to do a view table as well?

Comment: I think you can also use inline sql if you need to query a view or a table.

Comment: One way is to have a WHERE EXISTS in your Data Driven query that uses similar logic as your report query. `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'X' FROM <REPORT QUERY>)` If there are no rows from the report query, the exists clause will prevent any rows for the Data Driven query and the report won't run. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/data-driven-subscriptions?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Interesting, if I created a view and pulled the data from there could I have the where exists query pull and if it returns nothing then the data driven query doesn't send anything? If it does get a row back, it executes off of that and sends out?